# Finding a minimum value in a for loop and keeping the index of it

Tags: c++, for-loop, minimum

I am working on a homework assignment where I calculate the values in an interval of integers of a function (f(x) = x * x – 12 * x + 40) in a 'for' loop. I need to find a minimum value. That's all fine, but I also need to keep the index number for which the value was smallest. At the moment I reiterate the function again in another loop, but this looks really messy. Also I could derive x and calculate the answer using the known minimum, but that's also weird, because derivation is not so straightforward. Do you have any tips for me? Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "limits.h"
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int lBound, uBound, y, min;

    cout << "Give the lower and the upper bounds of integer numbers: " << endl;
    cin >> lBound >> uBound;        

    min=INT_MAX;
    int x = lBound;
    for (int i = x; i <=uBound; i ++) {
        y = i * i - 12 * i + 40;
        cout << x << " " << y << endl;
        if (y<min) {
            min=y;
        }
        x++;            
    }
    for (int i = lBound; i <= uBound; i++) {
        y = lBound * lBound - 12 * lBound + 40;
        if (y==min) {
            y = lBound;
            i=uBound; // terminates the loop
        }
        lBound++;
    }               
    cout << "smallest value of the function is " << min << " for x = " <<  y << endl;                
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please click the `{}` button when pasting code. (Please look at the preview before posting anything.) Please use the homework tag when asking about homework.

Comment: There is no right answer we can give to this question, because it's homework. It depends entirely on the instructor's intention. Perhaps you should use calculus to find the minima. (After all, depending on the polynomial, they might not be unique or integer values.) Perhaps you should store things in an array. All have advantages and disadvantages, which might be beside the point of the assignment.

Comment: So you managed to save the minimum value "y" in "min", but could not think of a way to save "i" into a "minI" variable?

Comment: I understand the fact that "i" of the corresponding min needs to be saved. What I can't get my head around is that min is known only after the loop has passed, therefore all "i's" have passed too...

Answer (score 3):

Here's a hint: Whenever you need to "keep something around" in a program, that means you need to store it in a variable. Whether that variable is local, global, or passed around depends on how long you need to keep it around. This is called the variable's "scope". It's considered good practice to keep the scope of any variable to a minimum, hence the guidelines discouraging globals.

Comment: +2.  No, Stackoverflow's software does not allow +2.  Maybe +3 will work....  This is an excellent answer.

Comment: well, in this way I store the minimum value, but I know it only after the loop has passed. Sorry i still don't see the solution...

Comment: Yes, you only know it is the minimum after the loop is complete. `min()` is at best an O(N) algorithm, which means it scales with the number of data points. Such is life.

Answer (score 1):

```
        i=uBound; // terminates the loop
```

This is not a very good coding practice. To terminate a loop, you should use a flow control construct like `break`. Doing so in this case would preserve the index of the minimum element.

**Edit:** If you want `i` to outlive the loop, you simply need to declare it outside. To wit:

change

```
for (int i = lBound; i <= uBound; i++) {
```

to

```
int i; // variable exists outside loop
for (i = lBound; i <= uBound; i++) {
```

Furthermore, just FYI, loop bounds are usually specified as [half-open intervals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-open_interval) to avoid the potential issue where `lbound` and `ubound` represent the limits of the `int` data type. This means that you usually use `<` instead of `<=`.

It's not clear if you're in an algebra class or a CS class…

Comment: No it wouldn't because `i` goes out of scope.

Comment: Thanks for this tip, it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: I do know this, I could as well assign "i" to another variable outside the for-loop, still it does not lead anywhere near the solution. It's a C++ introductory course I am doing.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was stuck "inside a box". A big relief after understanding the obvious.