# User is entering 10 numbers, find max negative value and its index/position

Tags: c++, for-loop

User is entering 10 numbers, find max negative value and its index/position.

ps: must use "for".
help plz -_-"

this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    double value, maxValue, index;

    cin >> value;
    maxValue = value;
    index = 1;

    for (int i = 2; i <= 10; i++) {
        cin >> value;

        if (value > maxValue&&value<0) {
            maxValue = value;
                index = i;
        }

    }
    cout << "Max value = " << maxValue << " index = " << index << endl;


}
```

Comment: I see what you have tried, but what problems did you experience with the code?

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: sometimes programm shows me non negative max value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding a minimum value in a for loop and keeping the index of it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871391/finding-a-minimum-value-in-a-for-loop-and-keeping-the-index-of-it)

Comment: What do you mean by `max negative value` ? max absolute value which is negative, or negative number nearest of `0` (so which one between `-42` and `-1`)

Comment: You haven't checked the first value to be negative, now suppose the user enters only non-negative numbers ...

Comment: " negative number nearest of 0" this^

Comment: can u show me this "check" plz?

Comment: @PhilipP.: BinkanSalaryman talks about `cin >> value;
    maxValue = value;
    index = 1;`. maxValue is unconditionally set even with positive number.

Answer (score 1):

change the line

```
if (value < maxValue && value<0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution I came up with:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    double maxValue;
    int index = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        double value;
        cin >> value;
        if(!(value < 0)) {
            continue;
        }
        if(index >= 0) {
            if(value > maxValue) {
                maxValue = value;
                index = i;
            }
        } else {
            maxValue = value;
            index = i;
        }
    }
    if (index >= 0) {
        cout << "Greatest negative value is " << maxValue << " at index " << (index+1) << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "No negative value issued" << endl;
    }
}
```